# Login Page Times Out Unless Cookies are Cleared

Tags: php, iis

We recently built a website internally that is 99% complete but we are running into some issues with sessions staying active.

Once every 24 hours or so, an admin user who goes to the website and tries to login gets a "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" from our IIS server. It doesn't matter if we put in correct information or false, it gives that error. The only solution is to go into the browser and clear "Cookie and session data" from the web browser and then it lets you log in like normal.

I have tried everything in my skillset to try to correct this (which, I will admit, IIS is not my strong point) and cannot find any differences in the configs from the working development site to the live site. To launch the site we even just left the development folder alone and just pointed the URL to the dev folder and made a new dev folder to ensure 100% compatibility.

The login code is as follows:

```php
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: admin.php");
    exit;
}

// Include config file. File contains SQL connection information
require "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";
$todayDate = date("Y-m-d");


// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                // Store result
                $stmt->store_result();

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if($stmt->num_rows == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    $stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if($stmt->fetch()){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session

                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;  

                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: admin.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        $stmt->close();
    }

    // Close connection
    $mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

I have attempted to clear the session data using a button that loads a clearSession.php file and redirects back to the admin page but it does nothing.

```php
<?php
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_write_close();
    setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    header("Location: http://web.address.too.admin.login");
?>
```

As soon as you clear cookies and sessions from the web browser manually, it works and everything is good until it fails after another 24 hours or so.

To help troubleshoot, we get the same error on a completely separate "non-user-authenticated-test-php-file". When the user clicks a button to alter some text, timeout error occurs:

```php
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $myString = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", " ", $_POST['textToStrip']);
    }
?>

<body style="margin:0 auto; text-align:center;">
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Strip"><br />
<textarea name="textToStrip" id="textToStrip" rows="40" cols="100"><?php echo $myString; ?></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Strip">
</form>
</body>
```

Any ideas on what I can look into in IIS or code to properly kill any associated data before logging in would be amazing.

Comment: could you please share what is your iis session state setting? also, check the IIS log for more information or you could run failed request tracing. provide the iis application pool recycling setting and connection time out value.

Comment: Session State Settings
- Enable Session State [True]
- Maximum Sessions [4294967295]
- New ID on Secure Connection [True]
- Time-out [00:20:00]
- Application Pool Recycling - 1740 Minutes
- Connection Time Out - 120 Seconds.

I started logging Failed Request Tracing....no logs have been produced.

All settings are the same for my DEV site as LIVE for these settings.

Comment: Some more updated information

1. Only does this on Chrome (and from multiple machines / networks). Logging in on IE works fine with no issue.
2. The website gets about 2 million page views a month so I'm wondering if the sessions just fill up or somehow gets confused with a duplicate session.